# Presenter not being injected in my Activity in Dagger 2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm learning Dagger 2 to build a clean architecture project. I have been looking around some SO questions about the same error but can't still figure it out why it's not working.

I have run the debugger to see if my View Activity is going to the presenter but it seems it's not injecting the presenter because it's not going to the presenter.

Here is my Activity where I inject the presenter.

### ApodDetail.kt

```
 @Inject lateinit var presenter : ApodDetailPresenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_apod_detail)
        (application as SimpleMVPApplication).apodComponent.inject(this)
        fetchApodDetails()
        imageview_apoddetail_reloadDetail.bringToFront()
    }
```

### PresenterModule.kt

```
@Module
class PresenterModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApodDetailPresenter(): ApodDetailPresenter {
        return ApodDetailPresenter(ApodDetailsInteractorImpl(), ImageCacheImpl())
    }

}
```

### AppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, PresenterModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(target: ApodDetail)
}
```

### AppModule.kt

```
@Module
class AppModule(private val app: Application) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(): Context = app
}
```

### SimpleMVPApplication.kt

```
class SimpleMVPApplication: Application() {

    lateinit var apodComponent: AppComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        apodComponent = initDagger(this)
    }

    private fun initDagger(app: SimpleMVPApplication): AppComponent =
            DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                    .appModule(AppModule(app))
                    .build()
}
```

And this is the presenter that I'm trying to inject into `ApodDetail.kt`

### ApodDetailPresenter.kt

```
class ApodDetailPresenter @Inject constructor(apodInteractor: ApodDetailsInteractorImpl, cache: ImageCacheImpl): ApodDetailContract.Presenter {

    var view: ApodDetailContract.View? = null
    var apodInteractor: ApodDetailsInteractorImpl? = null
    var cache: ImageCacheImpl? = null

    init {
        this.view = view
        this.apodInteractor = apodInteractor
        this.cache = cache
    }
```

Like I said above, it's not injecting the presenter into my Activity.

Comment: Why are you depending on `impl`s?

Comment: I was seeing in some repos that I should depend on interfaces, thats the right way to do it? Im depending on the implementation of the business logic because I was instantiating my presenter with that class before to work with

Comment: You should move `@Singleton` from Presenter module to the `@Inject constructor`'d presenter, then remove the PresenterModule entirely.

Answer (score 0):

In your Application class you're missing the call to add the presenter module in the component builder. You need:

```
private fun initDagger(app: SimpleMVPApplication): AppComponent =
            DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                    .appModule(AppModule(app))
                    .presenterModule(PresenterModule())
                    .build()
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace associated with not being able to inject? Or does it not compile?

Comment: No Stack , but it's compiling